# python configparser output issue

Tags: python, configparser

I want to add lines extracted from a file to a section , the line is not in the form of option=value, i use this program:

```
import configparser
f = open('inventory_file', 'r')
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.add_section('windows')
for line in f:
    if line[4] == '0':
        config.set('windows', line, 'None')

with open('example.cfg', 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

inventory_file:

```
W00VL9959061
W01V09908960
W01V09907745
W01V09907746
W01V09908317
W01V09907748
W00VL9968055
```

i got this result in example.cfg:

```
[windows]
w01v09908960
 = None
w01v09907745
 = None
w01v09907746
 = None
w01v09908317
 = None
w01v09907748
 = None
```

i want something like this:

```
[windows]
w01v09908960
w01v09907745
w01v09907746
w01v09908317
w01v09907748
```

Any idea pls how i can modify my script to get the expected result

Comment: i tried it :
i got this:
 cat example.cfg
[windows]
w01v09908960 = None
w01v09907745 = None
w01v09907746 = None
w01v09908317 = None
w01v09907748 = None
i want to get a rid of = None

Comment: Don't use `ConfigParser` if you don't need a config file. Config files will have a `parameter = value` format; don't write a config file if you want an Ansible inventory file.

Comment: @JL.Alex Please [edit] the question if you want to add details. Comments don't support preformatted text.

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 3.2 you can pass `allow_no_value` to the `ConfigParser` constructor (read [this section of the manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#customizing-parser-behaviour)) to allow keys without values. Then you can use `config.set(section,key)` to get what you want:

```py
import configparser
f = open('inventory_file', 'r')
config = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.add_section('windows')
for line in f:
  if line[4] == '0':
    config.set('windows', line.rstrip('\n'))

with open('example.cfg', 'w') as configfile:
  config.write(configfile)
```

The resulting file is:

```
[windows]
w01v09908960
w01v09907745
w01v09907746
w01v09908317
w01v09907748
```

Answer (score 0):

INI files have parameter-value pairs (*not always, it turns out. See [Psi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59503941/4518341)), so what you're looking for is not an INI file.

In this case you can do it manually:

```
with open('inventory_file') as inv, open('example.cfg', 'w') as cfg:
    print('[windows]', file=cfg)
    for line in inv:
        if line[4] == '0':
            print(line, file=cfg, end='')
```

Output in `example.cfg`:

```
[windows]
W01V09908960
W01V09907745
W01V09907746
W01V09908317
W01V09907748
```